# Getting a list of objects in gen 0 marked for GC

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, clr

I'm trying to debug memory issues in my ASP .NET application. For reasons (10+ year old reasons), this `WebMethod` goes from managed, to unsafe, to external c++ code through `DllImport`. Pinging this endpoint with the same query multiple times yields successful results 90% of the time, but every now and then it fails. It always seems to fail after GC occurs SOMETIMES. Meaning sometimes it succeeds after GC happens, sometimes it fails. Calling `GC.Collect(0)` at any point in the managed or unmanaged code seems to stop this bug from occurring. Can't do that, though.

I have tried attaching memory profilers to get an idea of how this thing is acting. Unfortunately when I start a profiling session, the error stops happening. Schrodinger's bug.

The only idea I'm left with is to log to disk each query every object (type and mem location) marked for GC in gen 0 and compare the differences between successful GCs and unsuccessful GCs. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to do this anywhere in Microsoft's docs or online. I'm sure this is possible, but probably requires some weird reflection stuff? I don't know.

Anyone know how this is accomplished?

Thanks!

Comment: The only way to get a list of gen 0 objects is through either the debugger or profiler apis, you can't get it through reflection. If you want help solving the actual issue, you will need to provide a lot more information about the error and the code that triggers it.

Comment: I'm not particularly looking for help fixing the actual problem. I have ideas of what it is, it's just finding it. I'll look into other profilers to see if I can figure out how to do this. If I find a solution that doesn't prevent this bug from happening, I'll comment on it.

Comment: Also, downvote...for what reason? It's totally a valid question.

Comment: I didn't cast that down vote, but my guess is they thought you wanted help solving the bug and down-voted for the lack of detail.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as objects "marked for GC". Once GC occurred garbage collector traverses a graph of objects and deletes all objects which can't be reached from GC roots and compacts heaps. There are some details about finalizers and large objects heap in .NET before v.4, but overall GC works in that way.